# Stop Service with intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an Intent that starts a service which plays music in the background:

```
 final Intent music_intent=new Intent(this, MediaService.class);
 startService(music_intent);
```

I want onPause to stop the service:

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopService(xxxxxxx);
}
```

What do I type in the "xxxxxxx"

Comment: How do I stop the service when app goes on background and start when it gets on foreground?

Comment: You can Stop service when you press back. Call stop service action in onBackPressed(); .

Comment: I have disabled the back press

Comment: I want, when the user clicks the home button(the app goes in the background) from any activity of my app, the service to stop

Comment: if you disable the back press then call in onDestroy() or onPause();

Comment: I already tried that but the app isn't destroyed with the press of home button

Comment: if you press Home button then call override onPause(); and your action in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is stopped exactly as it was started.

```
final Intent music_intent=new Intent(this, MediaService.class);
stopService(music_intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stop service like this

```
Intent music_intent=new Intent(this, MediaService.class);
stopService(music_intent);
```

Or

```
stopService(new Intent(MyService.MY_SERVICE));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create one Intent object which you will pass to `startServcie()` and the service will start and it will keep on running until you call `stopService()` with the same intent you passed to start the service. You have to pass intent object as a parameter in both the methods above.

I highly recommend you to start service in `onStart()` and stop in `onPause()`

Answer (score 0):

to stop a service you have to call stopService for the same intent that started it
so you have to make the intent start it global property and onPause call it like this stopService(intent);